# MySQL create table and trigger

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

Can anyone help me understand what this code does?

```
CREATE TABLE `exams` (

`id` int(11) NOT NULL, `score` int(2) NOT NULL, `class` int(11) NOT NULL, `date` date NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`class`,`date`,`id`));

CREATE TRIGGER `trig3` BEFORE INSERT ON `exams` FOR EACH ROW SET @xxx = @xxx + 1;

SET @xxx = 0;

INSERT INTO `exams` VALUES (10001,24,1,'2013-09-16'), (10005,30,1,'2013-09-16'), (10083,30,1,'2014-03-21'), (10120,26,1,'2014-03-21'), (10035,23,1,'2014-07-22'), (10005,28,2,'2014-01-23'), (10001,27,2,'2014-06-30'), (10001,25,4,'2014-01-23'), (10083,22,4,'2014-01-23'), (10120,30,4,'2014-01-23'), (10005,22,4,'2014-03-21');

SELECT @xxx;
```

I understand the creation of the table and the insertion of values but i don't get the rest of it.

Comment: In MySQL, an identifier that starts with `@` character is a user-defined variable. The `SET @xxx = ` statement assigns a value. For each row insert into the table, the trigger `trig3` will be fired. When the trigger is fired, it will increment the value stored in the user defined variable `@xxx`. The `SELECT` statement at the end retrieves the current value of the user-defined variable, which will be a count of the number of times the trigger was fired. Assuming no errors, that would be the number of rows that were inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seams to be a workaround way to count or check if the multi insert inserted all records or not.

```
    SELECT @xxx;

| @xxx |
| ---- |
| 11   |
```

But MySQL doesn't have a native way to find that out.

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c3iKaNBjZtGbYg9AABz7fM/0)

A more easy MySQL code to do the same without needing the TRIGGER code and SET. 
 
But it will require a new table structure to function.

```
CREATE TABLE `esami` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  , `id_studente` int(11) NOT NULL
  , `voto` int(2) NOT NULL
  , `id_corso` int(11) NOT NULL
  , `data` date NOT NULL
  , UNIQUE KEY (`id_corso`,`data`,`id_studente`)    
);
```

And the query to test if all records where inserted by the multi insert.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  esami
WHERE
  id BETWEEN LAST_INSERT_ID() AND LAST_INSERT_ID() + 11;
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rZvDt21p9yjJB23Jrra8JQ/0)